# header issues building Qt app

Tags: qt, ubuntu, build, include, wireshark

I need to install wireshark on Ubuntu 16.04, but it appears that there are no binaries for that situation, so I'm forced to build it; that's OK, but having (finally) gotten "configure" to run, when I then run "make" I get "Undefined reference" always to Qt header files. Where is the path to the Qt includes defined? Can I change it? Will that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://launchpad.net/~wireshark-dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable) PPA, no need to compile the sources.

Also, remember to enable the **universe** repository, as suggested in the PPA instructions.

Comment: I tried this, and, as I thought, since the machine will not connect to the internet, the apt-get actions don't work. That is WHY I need to install wireshark in the first place! I could not find a .deb version of the binaries that I could install on the machine in question using dpkg; as far as I can tell I need to build it. But that should be possible - I DO have Qt installed (well maybe too many versions!)

Comment: Besides Qt you may need other dependencies... However, I'm afraid that this question is off-topic here on SO. I would suggest to ask at (https://askubuntu.com)[https://askubuntu.com] for help.

Comment: I was able to re-establish my internet connection without building wireshark. However, now I have a large number of packages that I installed manually that have numerous dependency problems - can anyone recommend the best way to clean them up?